# Mysql Query for Combinations

Tags: mysql

can anyone please guide me with writing MySQL query for following scenario.

The data in table is like this,

```
Table Name: Vals

        V1  | V2 | V3      |
+-----------+----+---------+
|       143 |  1 |       1 |             
|      2003 |  2 |       6 |
```

I want result to be like this which is basically Combinations of columns with particular Column constant.

```
        V1  | V2 | V3      |
+-----------+----+---------+
|       143 |  1 |       1 |             
|       143 |  1 |       6 |              
|       143 |  2 |       1 |             
|       143 |  2 |       6 |   
|      2003 |  1 |       1 |             
|      2003 |  1 |       6 |          
|      2003 |  2 |       1 |             
|      2003 |  2 |       6 |
```

Comment: can you post your database code? I don't understand which values v2 v3 come from. As far as I know, I think you should use the join for table. It should be left join with val1 is a key.

Comment: You really should add what comes in as a constant and what should come from which table as at the moment your description is quite confusing as to what you really want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like this do get all combinations

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.V1,
                b.V2,
                c.V3
FROM Vals a,
     Vals b,
     Vals c
```

To get it sorted then you add `ORDED BY` and then query looks like

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.V1,
                b.V2,
                c.V3
FROM Vals a,
     Vals b,
     Vals c
ORDER BY 1,
         2,
         3
```

Tested it on my table and it worked, hope it helps you.